# Encountering an infinity loop. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am encountering an infinity loop. It keeps asking for `social_media input`. I am trying to end the loop with `if not`, when I am entering a blank input with "enter", but it ignore it. How come?

```
while True:
    if confirm_social_media == 'n':
        victims.append(victim_data)
        continue
    while True:
        social_media = input("\nType of social media: "
                             "\n'i' = Instagram"
                             "\n's' = Snapchat"
                             "\n't' = Twitter"
                             "\n'y' = Youtube"
                             "\n'f' = Facebook"
                             "\n'o' = Other"
                             "\nOr blank for next")
        if not social_media:
            break

        if social_media == 'i':
            iinput = input("Instagram " + str(inumbr) + ": ")
            if family_members == 'm':
                mother_instagram.append(iinput)
            elif family_members == 'f':
                father_instagram.append(iinput)
            elif family_members == 'o':
                other_instagram.append(iinput)
```

Comment: You don't have `break` for your outer while loop

Comment: `continue` means "start the loop again", not "move on to the code after the loop". You want `break`. (Maybe; it's hard to say since you don't show where or how `confirm_social_media` gets set.)

Comment: We need a [mcve] to say for sure, but I suspect that the problem is related to the fact that you have _two_ endless loops.

Comment: Complains about encountering an infinitely loop... code is structured in while True loops with breaks... no comments

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I appreciate your constructive answer, and that you acknowledge, that we are some people who are learning and learning the logic of python. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite loop is caused by your first outer while loop at the very top of the code that you shared. You have nothing to break that loop, so it will execute the inner while loop infinitely even if you break it with the `break` statement you inserted in your `if not social_media:` condition because you are not breaking the outer while loop.

As a solution, simply remove the top while loop or add another condition that is changed in your code, for example inside your `if not social_media:` add a boolean that will be used to break your outer while loop:

```
continue_loop = True
while continue_loop :
    if confirm_social_media == 'n':
        victims.append(victim_data)
        continue
    while True:
        social_media = input("\nType of social media: "
                             "\n'i' = Instagram"
                             "\n's' = Snapchat"
                             "\n't' = Twitter"
                             "\n'y' = Youtube"
                             "\n'f' = Facebook"
                             "\n'o' = Other"
                             "\nOr blank for next")
        if not social_media:
            continue_loop = False
            break

    if social_media == 'i':
            iinput = input("Instagram " + str(inumbr) + ": ")
            if family_members == 'm':
                mother_instagram.append(iinput)
            elif family_members == 'f':
                father_instagram.append(iinput)
            elif family_members == 'o':
                other_instagram.append(iinput)
```

Here is some additional information about while loops from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm):

> A while loop statement in Python programming language repeatedly executes a target statement as long as a given condition is true.
>
> A loop becomes infinite loop if a condition never becomes FALSE. You must use caution when using while loops because of the possibility that this condition never resolves to a FALSE value. This results in a loop that never ends. Such a loop is called an infinite loop.

I suggest that you read more about while loops and Python in general. [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm) or the [official Python documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) are good places to get started.

Comment: good simple code that fits and fix OP's problem. However, I would have named the variable "continue_loop" instead of "end_loop", because when it's true, you actually continue the loop ;) .

Comment: @Pac0 Yes I completely agree with you, it does make more sense in this context, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: I see the difference now and it makes good sense. I thought I had ensured that the while loop would turn False with the `if not social_media:` and then break out of it. But that did of course not apply to the outer loop. How it is constructed in your example gave me an "Aha" experience. :)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that the name of your variables is slightly frightening,  why don't you have a break condition for the outer loop ?

It seems you are breaking out of the inner one correctly, but you don't have any code that breaks out of the outer (first line in your code)